# MySQL (InnoDB) Select from 2 tables and always get empty result set

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm a little confused.  I'm using MySQL 5+ with InnoDB as my engine.  If I run the following statement and the table 'user_temp' is empty I always get an empty result set no matter what's in the 'users' table.

```
SELECT * FROM `users`, `user_temp`
```

If I put something in 'user_temp' I'll get back all the results.  Is this suppose to work like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Without any criteria comparing records from the users table to the user_temp table, that's a cartesian product.

Comment: cartesian join means that you are joining every row of one table to every row of the other table (not what you want probably), and if one table has nothing, it's like multiplying by zero.

Comment: And I would recommend explicit joins rather than implicit joins. You have a lot more flexibility with the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to unconditionally get results from `users`, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    u.*, ut.*
FROM 
    `users` u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `user_temp` ut
    ON ut.user_id = u.user_id
```

[**Here**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) is a good visual explanation of the various join types.

Answer (score 2):

That's an `INNER JOIN`.  But you are specifying a join field.  I think you want an `OUTER JOIN`.  Maybe even a `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Your example can be re-written as:

```
SELECT * FROM users, user_temp
INNER JOIN user_temp
ON users.id_user = user_temp.id_temp
```

If no rows match on `id_user`, which would definitely be the case if one of the tables was empty, then you would get 0 records in your result set.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM users, user_temp
LEFT JOIN user_temp
ON users.id_user = user_temp.id_temp
```

Comment: The SQL above demostrates the explicit `JOIN` syntax, which I make a habit of using.  If you list multiple tables in your `FROM` clause with a `WHERE` clause to match on a field, you get an `INNER JOIN` implicitly